# ffmpeg missing config.h in libavutil (No Such File or Directory) CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, codeblocks

When I test the [ffmepg encoding/decoding exapmle c program](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/decoding__encoding_8c-source.html) in CodeBlocks, it shows:

```
/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/internal.h    fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory
```

error happens in many other header file within **ffmpeg_source/libavutil** folder.
I searched the folder but did not find config.h file. There are config.h in other folders but does not work for the header files within libavutil folder.

I tried download newest ffmepg zip file and also cannot find the config.h file in it.

Where should I find the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`config.h` file is a platform specific configuration file for the source. It is generated by the `configure` script provided within the software package (usually in the root directory of the decompressed tarball or whatever archive the source comes from). This script *must* be run before any build operation in order to have the source code configured to work within the target environment.

Additionally I have to mention that "public" headers of a lib never include `config.h`, so you should never include a header of a lib into your code if it includes `config.h`.

Comment: I agree that public headers should not include `config.h` but some of the officia ffmpeg examples do, such as https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/extract_mvs.c

Answer (score 0):

configure ffmpeg code before importing ide, then you will find config.h on root that defines platform specific variables considering your platform